# C++ Builder - Copy a Link to a String Based On Certain Words in It

Tags: c++, c++builder

This's my first post here.

I have 4 links in a `Memo` or `TStringList`:

```
http://website.com/text/book&id=20/programming
http://website.com/text/book&id=10/programming
http://website.com/text/book&id=40/programming
http://website.com/text/book&id=30/programming
```

What I want to do is to copy each link based on its `"id number"`, as shown above to separate string, and NOT based on its
index in `TMemo` or in `TStringList`.

This's because the id number of each link is always change every time or dynamics (it's a random id).

So let's say :

1. if the link containts `id=10` then it should be copied to a string called `"id10"`.

   - final result is `id10` containts: `http://website.com/text/book&id=10/programming`
2. if the link containts `id=30` then it should be copied to a string called `"id30"`.

   - final result is `id30` containts: `http://website.com/text/book&id=30/programming`
3. so on and on until all links are copied into a separate different string.

I've tried to resolve this problem using `substring` function, such as:

```
int p = 0;
String id10, id20, id30, id40;
p = Memo1->Lines->Text.Pos("id=20");
if (p != 0)
{
  id10 = Memo1->Lines->Text.SubString(p + 1, Memo1->Lines->Text.Length());
  ShowMessage(id10);
}

......
```

Unfortunately, its always failed. Because I am new to c++ and the sort but I don't know what to do with all of it. I am sorry.

So I need your help to handle this situation.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling .Pos() from the text property is getting the index for the position of the found string within the entire text of the memo control. Here is a short example of how to read each line from a TMemo in C++ Builder:

```
AnsiString id10;

for (int i = 0; i < Memo1->Lines->Count; i++)
{
    AnsiString line = Memo1->Lines->Strings[i];

    if (line.Pos("id=10") > 0)
    {
        id10 = line;
        ShowMessage(id10);
    }
}
```

Using the above snippet, you should be able to deduce how to make it do what you want.

Comment: @Michal Glad to help!